# Doubles and Code Accuracy: What Is Wrong?

Tags: math, double, primitive, exponentiation

I'm having trouble with the accuracy of the exponentiation of doubles and their sums in the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(double A = 1; A <= 100; A++)
    {
        for(double B = 1; B <= 100; B++)
        {
            for(double C = 1; C <= 100; C++)
            {
                for(double x = 3; x <= 100; x++)
                {
                    for(double y = 3; y <= 100; y++)
                    {
                        for(double z = 3; z <= 100; z++)
                        {
                            if((Math.pow(A, x) + Math.pow(B, y)) == (Math.pow(C, z)))
                            {
                                System.out.println(A+"^"+x+" + "+B+"^"+y+" = "+C+"^"+z);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

in which the 1st five terms of the output are:

```
1.0^3.0 + 2.0^53.0 = 2.0^53.0
1.0^3.0 + 2.0^54.0 = 2.0^54.0
1.0^3.0 + 2.0^55.0 = 2.0^55.0
1.0^3.0 + 2.0^56.0 = 2.0^56.0
1.0^3.0 + 2.0^57.0 = 2.0^57.0
```

It is clear that adding "1.0^3.0" (which is basically "1.0") with "2.0^53.0" does *NOT* equal "2.0^53.0"; there's also something wrong with the y-value.

It may be that my conditional statement is flawed or I might have to use a different primitive data type...Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because double-precision has exactly [53 bits of mantissa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary64).

Comment: @J0nathan: Use `long`, or `BigDecimal`/`BigInteger`.